# Is there a term for configuration items which only affect future data, not current data?

Tags: user-interface, configuration, usability

If I want to create a setting which only affects data inputted or outputted in future, and not data already in the system, is there a term for this kind of setting?

An example of this type of setting would be "log level". Changing your log level does not generally result in messages being removed from past log files.

An example of a type of setting which is **not** like this would be the page size in a wordprocessor. Generally, that results in the document contents being reflowed for the new page size.

Comment: actually I think a setting called "log level" would be understood to affect logging moving forward into the future not the past even without any sort of special name.  You should provide the specific settings you're thinking of; might help answer the question.

Comment: I'm not aware of such a term. If you try to coin a term, then I suggest you try to coin a _pair_ of terms: one term for what you want, plus an opposing term. For example, "static configuration" and "dynamic configuration" are a nice pair of terms (but they already have meanings that are unsuited to your needs). How about "future variant configuration" and "time invariant configuration"? I mention those not as a good pair of names, but rather in the hope that they might inspire people to think of more appropriate terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-retroactive, with the opposite being retroactive.